# Normal distribution - absolute value solved

Tags: normal-distribution, absolute-value

The random variable Y is normally distribution with mean = 8 and S.D = 5.
Show that, P(|X−8|<6.2) = 0.785

What I did: (6.2 + 8)/5 = 2.84. The value of 2.84 is 0.9977 in the table. Normally, I would just double the value I have got if it was an absolute value question but here I'm stumped.

Comment: You want the area from 1.8 to 14.2. You can look up the one sided tails for each and subtract

Comment: I would say: P(|X−8|<6.2) = P(-6.2 < X - 8 < 6.2) = P( 1.8 < X < 14.2)

Comment: @georg did the same thing, and subtracted the two, answer isn't 0.785.

Comment: @4956 - Excel:  0,892512303 - 0,107487697 = 0,785024606

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Z=(X-8)/5$ is a standard normal, so $$ P(|X-8|<6.2) = P\left(|Z|<\frac{6.2}{5}\right) = \Phi\left(\frac{6.2}{5}\right)-\Phi\left(-\frac{6.2}{5}\right)\approx0.785$$ where $\Phi$ is the standard normal CDF.

Comment: thank you. but where did 8 go?

Comment: @4956 $Z=(X-8)/5.$ It went into $Z.$

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm asking a lot of questions - but why have we taken a -6.2/5. Why the negative sign?

Comment: @4956 $|Z|<\frac{6.2}{5}$ means the region $-\frac{6.2}{5}< Z < \frac{6.2}{5}.$ There are many ways to express the area under the bell curve over this region in terms of the CDF. I chose one. I have edited in a different choice that might be more apparent.

Comment: My first choice used the fact that the CDF evaluated at the negative value is the tail area, so I subtracted off twice the tail area, leaving the middle.

Comment: thank you so much for your explanation and the edit made to your post. This is quite clear now.